# Is it possible to get bitcoin by mining bitcoin and get fee?

Tags: solo-mining

I know it's hard to mining bitcoin.

How about get bitcoin fee by mining bitcoin solo and without a pool?

I survey two ways, and want to ask which one is better?

1. Mining bitcoin solo without using a pool.
2. Set up my own private pool and disable payouts.

If any one is possible, how to mining on ubuntu?

Thank you~

Comment: Get 'bitcoin fee' or get 'free bitcoin'?

Comment: get bitcoin transaction fee.

Comment: How much hashing power do you have?

Comment: I haven't calculate that and do not know how. I'm curious about is it possible to get the transaction fee?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you plan to allow other miners to join your pool, mining solo and mining in your own pool would lead to equivalent results.

Using either method, you would be able to collect the transactions fees from each block you find.

Comment: I have a question about: if someone A who find one block and not mining bitcoin anymore, is A will still get transaction fee on that block? Or others who mining other blocks will get that transaction fee?

Comment: Transactions are included in the block, so the miner who successfully creates a block with a valid Proof of Work will collect the transaction fees for transactions they included in that block.

Answer (score 2):

The odds are extremely low that you would ever find a block. Maybe 7 years ago this was possible to do. But not today. You would need a farm of expensive ASIC mining equipment, lots of cheap electricity, and a way to vent the heat that comes from running the mining equipment. Take your money and buy some on an exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Getting bitcoin transaction fees is the same as mining a bitcoin block (and getting the block reward). My understanding is that you think it's possible to just mine transactions on their own and get the fees, without participating in the very hard job of creating blocks. However, this is not possible.

Because transactions are verified by miners putting them into blocks, there is no way you can verify transactions (and therefore get the fees) without creating a block.

Since the total combined hashrate of the bitcoin network is so large and takes ~10 minutes to create a single block, your machine on its own would probably take several millenia before ever finding a block (and thus getting transaction fees from the transactions you place in the block + the 12.5 BTC block reward). This is why pools exist in the first place, because no one has enough hashpower to find blocks on their own (except a few huge miners) and the only way to mine BTC is to create blocks.

Comment: If one person A get a block a' on bitcoin, and not mining anymore. Could I say all transactions fee on block a' will happened one thing that nobody receive those fees?